# Restrict access of the main obj to the properties of its properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, chaining

Ok, I'm creating a chaining method with javascript and I'm trying to archive that the main obj or class have access to 4 property that are functions and the properties must have access to some functions that the main obj cannot.

Here a example:

```
var Main = function(){

return {
 property1:function(){
return this;
},
property2:function(){
return this;    
},
etc:function(){
    return this;
}...

}
}
```

To execute as you know its like this:

```
  Main().property1().property2().etc();
```

Main have access to its properties but `Main` must not have access to this properties that are properties of `Main`'s properties. In simplier way: `just the properties of Main must have access, not Main`.

Here an example:

```
Main().property().innerProperty1().innerProperty2().etc()//cool, property1 can access to innerProperty 1 and 2 and etc()
```

but if i want to do this:

```
Main().innerProperty() // ERROR, Main does not have acccess to innerProperty()
```

Could that be possible in javascrip? Remember that must be chainable.

Comment: I'm confused by your example because all you are doing for each "property" is just returning Main so it will have access to all of the properties accessible by Main. But what is the point of chaining itself?

Comment: because the are inner property that if main have access will have lack of meaning. So Main must not have access to it 1: because of lack of meaning and 2 because the inner properties dont affect in any way on Main

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not very sure what you are asking, but this is what i came up with. I made two JS classes to demonstrate what you are saying.

```
function Owner(name) {
    this.Name = name;

    this.ChangeName = function (newName) {
        this.Name = newName;
        return this;
    };
}


function Car(make, model, owner) {

    this.Make = make;
    this.Model = model;
    this.Owner = owner;

    this.UpdateMake = function (newMake) {
        this.Make = newMake;
        return this;
    };

    this.UpdateModel = function (newModel) {
        this.Model = newModel;
        return this;
    };

    this.UpdateOwner = function (newOwner) {
        this.Owner = newOwner;
        return this;
    };

}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whytheday/zz45L/18/

Car would not have access to Owner's name unless it went through Owner first.